# Can we upload files like Docs or PDF or Any Other file types to snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My Goal is to upload files to snowflake.
Basically I'm looking for Google/One Drive feature but limited to upload and download features.

Key Points

1. Files can be of size 1-10 gb
2. File Types can vary
3. These Files are not staging files
4. I can download these files from file link or using API

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the documentation on unstructured data? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/unstructured.html

Comment: @NickW I was able to upload files to Stage Directory in snowflake.
create stage mystage
  directory = (enable = true)
  file_format = (compression='None');
After I uploaded file, it still got compressed to gz format. 
Any Idea why? and How do I decompress to get original file while using Get command?
Also How to decompress while using Get_Presigned_Url ?